# Get rid of space between text and td's border

Tags: html, css, html-table, valign

I have a `<td>` that has `valign="bottom"` and the text contained in the td has `font-size:100px`.

How do I get rid of the space between the text and the border in a `<td>`.

Please find sample code here
http://jsfiddle.net/jM8JC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do this, you shouldn't. The reason there's extra space between the the lower edge of the word and the bottom border is that's where the lower parts, the [descender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) of the `y`, `g`, etc, goes: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jM8JC/17/ (in this demo I've set `line-height` to `1` (no unit), which places the bottom edge of the `y` against the lower border.

Adjusting the [`line-height` to `0.65`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jM8JC/24/) places the lower edge of the word `test` against the bottom border, but it's a fairly arbitrary measurement, and dependent upon the `font-size` used, and, probably, the particular browser.

And if you add `overflow: hidden` you can also hide the descending portion of the `y` if you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jM8JC/25/

Comment: The "lower part" is called a [descender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender).

Comment: 'Preciate it; I assumed it was something like that but, to my shame, I went to do 'other things' and...forgot to check. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `height:200px;` in the table tag:

`<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <tr>

        <td valign="bottom" class="test" style="font-size:100px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">

            test

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>​`

http://jsfiddle.net/jM8JC/26/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `line-height:75px`for the `TD`

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="200px">
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" class="test" style="font-size:100px; line-height:75px;">
            test
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

See an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jM8JC/22/

Answer (score 0):

Just set a line height smaller than text size. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jM8JC/16/